# How to update users based on lastLoginDate in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, authorization

I need a bit of help on this one; its more about verifying....

I'm trying to find out if the user's lastLoginDate has been exactly a year from today.

This is what I've done so far and I think it makes sense, however, I would like if somebody could tell me if there's something wrong.

I'm using this code to suspend the users account if their last login has been exactly 1 year.

```js
exports.checkLastLoginDate = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let oneYearAgo = new Date()
  oneYearAgo.setFullYear(oneYearAgo.getFullYear() - 1)

  let users = await User.find()

  const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => user.lastLoginDate <= oneYearAgo)

  const inactiveUsers = filteredUsers.map(async (u) => {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: u._id },
      {
        $addToSet: { role: 'suspended' },
      },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        setDefaultsOnInsert: false,
      }
    )
  })

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: inactiveUsers })
})
```

Does it makes sense or do you guys think this is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to optimize your code by using `updateMany` instead of retrieving all users and filtering them in plain JS:

```
exports.checkLastLoginDate = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let oneYearAgo = new Date();
  oneYearAgo.setFullYear(oneYearAgo.getFullYear() - 1);

  const inactiveUsers = await User.updateMany(
    { lastLoginDate: { $lte: oneYearAgo } },
    { $addToSet: { role: 'suspended' } },
    { new: true, runValidators: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: false }
  );

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: inactiveUsers });
});
```

Comment: Yees, can not believe I did not think pf that lol.